# В каком порядке хранятся пары в Dictionary<string, string> C#?

Tags: c#, коллекции, словари, order

Есть задача: организовать перемешивание пар ключ-значение. Для хранения пар была выбрана коллекция `Dictionary<string, string>`.

1. В каком порядке хранятся элементы этой коллекции по мере их добавления?
2. Можно ли к ним обращаться по индексу, как в массиве или в листе?
3. Есть ли вообще какая-то определённая упорядоченность в этой коллекции и меняется ли она от очерёдности добавления элементов?

Comment: нет, никто не гарантирует порядок

Comment: @Grundy, а если создать List<Dictionary<string, string>> и попробовать переставлять элементы листа?

Comment: здесь элементы - отдельные словари - если переставите целый словарь, на его внутренних элементах это никак не скажется

Comment: @Grundy, а если в словаре всего один элемент, и мы будем переставлять элементы листа с одной парой, тогда элементов листа будет столько, сколько должно было быть пар в словаре.

Comment: а если в словаре один элемента, тогда словарь не нужен - можно использовать структуру `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо!))) Это будет более аккуратное решение!

Comment: кстати микрософт открыл исходники и можно посмотреть как именно работает тот или иной класс, например, для [Dictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0)

Comment: @Grundy, да, это будет очень полезно, надо посмотреть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary представляет собой реализацию стандартной [Hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

При добавлении элемента вычисляется хэшкод его ключа и затем — индекс корзины в которую он будет добавлен по модулю от величины коллекции:

```
int bucketNum = (hashcode & 0x7fffffff) % capacity;
```

Это означает, что :

1. Нету какого то правила, которое определяет порядок.
2. Нет, но у справочника есть Keys\Values. Так же вы можете завести
   List> и обращаться по индексу
3. Нет.

Answer (score 5):

Dictonary реализован как [хеш-таблица](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), поэтому вам никто не гарантирует ни порядок элементов, ни то что он останется неизменным при добавлении, удалении. Обратится по индексу тоже нельзя.

Но к Dictonary можно применить Linq, тогда:

```
Dictonary<string, string> dict = new Dictonary<string, string>()
{
     {"red", "dog"}
   , {"yellow", "cat"}
   , {"green", "hamster"}
};
var sorted = dict.OrderBy(n => n.Key);
```

позволит вам получить сортировку.

NB! sorted уже не словарь, это IEnumerable.

Comment: нужно отметить, что _sorted_ уже не словарь, и соответственно обратится к нему по ключу будет нельзя

Comment: @Grundy, да sorted не словарь, но и физически он занимает немного(относительно) места, поэтому если храним данные в словаре, но в каком то месте программы нам важен порядок, это именно тот случай.

Comment: я просто хотел, чтобы вы добавили в ответ, что результат уже не будет словарем, как может показаться сейчас. :-)

Comment: @Grundy, я как то это посчитал очевидным, но да вы правы